# Here navigation API NavigationManager getEta() always returns an invalid/unknown

Tags: java, android, here-api

I am evaluating the new Here SDK for Android and have successfully implemented map display, routing, and navigation.  I have been asked to add an ETA and so looked in the SDK documentation and found the getEta() method for NavigationManager.

Whenever I call this method, the returned value is 0; i.e. toString() on the returned Date object is "ETA: Wed Dec 31 18:59:59 EST 1969"

The exact code I'm using is this, approximately once a second:

```
Date eta = NavigationManager.getInstance().getEta(true, Route.TrafficPenaltyMode.DISABLED);
Log.d(logTag, "ETA: " + eta.toString());
```

I assume I'm missing some setup call somewhere, but nothing in the SDK documentation is jumping out at me.  I can verify that a destination is set and route calculation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is NavigationManager.getEta() that you can/should use when you are in navigation mode to get the estimated time of arrival (in form of date) taking your position into account. 
When navigation is not running, you get the result you wrote.

If you want to get the estimated time to arrival for a route outside navigation (e.g. in route overview) you can call Route.getTta() on your Route object and you'll get back the duration of the route trip (based on your setup in routeoptions/routeplan) in seconds.

Comment: As I said in my question, this is during navigation mode, after a route has been set and the route calculation is completed (onCalculateRouteFinished has been called).

Edit to add: It does eventually start reporting an Eta, but usually not until several seconds after route calculation is complete.

Comment: How about adding a check after navigation is initiated navigationmanager.getRunningState() ==  NavigationManager.NavigationState.RUNNING